# Verification of proof if $C$ is a positively oriented circle and $z_{0}$ lies outside $C$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Show that if $C$ is a positively oriented circle and $z_{0}$ lies outside $C$, then

$$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{z - z_{0}} = 0 $$

$\underline{Proof}$

WE have to prove $z_{0}$ lies outside $C$ if $C$ is positively oriented, i.e with $0$ to $2\pi$ limits.  Let define $C$ with $z=e^{it}$

Therefore $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it} dt}{e^{it} -z_{0}} = \left[\log(e^{it} - z_{0})\right]\Biggr|_{0}^{2\pi}$$
$$ = \log(1 - z_{0}) - \log (1-z_{0}) = 0 $$

this indicates $z_{0}$ lies on the circle or outside the circle

Can you guys check if this is correct or not?

Comment: It seems that you should assume $z_0$ lies outside the circle, rather than try to prove it...

Comment: I'm proving the statement above that  $z_{0}$ lies outside the circle is just the condition attached to the proven statement.

Comment: Why do you end your calculation with "this indicates $z_0$ lies on the circle or outside the circle" if you understand that this is part of the hypotheses you are making?

Comment: As a critique, you don't know the radius of $C$; that is, you cannot say exactly that $C=\{e^{it}:t\in[0,2\pi]\}$.

Comment: So what do you suggests to do?

Comment: Start with assuming $z_0$ lies outside of $C$, a positively-oriented circle. This means $C=c+re^{i\theta}$ for some $c\in\Bbb C$ and $r>0$ (we don't know that it is centered at the origin). Now take this and perform similar calculations to those you've already done. This lets you show that the integral equals $0$, so you are done.

Comment: This kind of argument using logarithms in the complex plane is totally wrong. As you have observed your arguments seems to give the value 0 even for points inside, but the correct value is $2\pi i$ for points inside. Let me repeat: use logarithm in complex plane without understanding its properties is dangerous.